# type of data object with pd library

Tags: python, django

I have this code:

```
x = { 'Expired': dead_247, 'Unknown': unsure_247, 'Alive': alive_247 }

    data = pd.Series(x).reset_index(name='value').rename(columns={'index':'status'})
    data['angle'] = data['value']/data['value'].sum() * 2*pi
    data['color'] = ["#c0c4c1", "#009695", "#53e305"]

    data["value"] = data['value'].astype(str)
    data["value"] = data["value"].str.pad(10, side = "left")

    sep = []
    for i in range(len(data.index)):
        sep.append(': ')
    data['legend'] = data['status'] + sep + data['value'].astype(str)
```

I print 'data' object by print(data) and see this output. Please tell me what type of data structure the 'data' is. Is it a List, or dictionary.

```
web_1  |     status       value     angle    color               legend
web_1  | 0  Expired        1422  1.553859  #c0c4c1  Expired:       1422
web_1  | 1  Unknown        3080  3.365602  #009695  Unknown:       3080
web_1  | 2    Alive        1248  1.363724  #53e305    Alive:       1248
```

Could you show me how to add 1 more line into data['legend'] : Total = 5750  . (This is the sum of 1422 + 3080 +1248)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, `data` is a Pandas `DataFrame`:

```
In [8]: type(data)
Out[8]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

All the columns in a DataFrame all always have to be the same length, so you can't add a value to the `legend` column without adding values to all the others, as well.

Comment: Thank you for your help!